# How does ‘Trent’s circuit board strategy’ work?

Tags: hardware, nintendo, glitches, game-controller

For those of you who are unaware, professional speedrunner Trent Hall discovered a now-banned speedrunning trick in *GoldenEye 007* for the Nintendo 64. The trick (called ‘Trent's circuit board strategy’) consisted of plugging a dismantled second controller into the second controller port. Then, when there is a countdown timer, pushing down on the exposed circuit board to freeze the game while the countdown continued. Because the Elite *GoldenEye* Rankings are ranked in IGT (in-game time) as opposed to RTA (real-time attack), this strategy would save tens of seconds on many levels.

[image: where to press down on the controller]

My question is... well, what causes the N64 to behave in this way? This seems like an extremely unlikely result.

A video by former *GoldenEye* champion Ryan "RWhiteGoose" White on the strategy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tr6txZdNcc0

Read more about Trent: http://www.shootersforever.com/forums_message_boards//viewtopic.php?t=6332&view=previous&sid=6a6704f2fa89f78f2d42239d5cd4205f

Comment: That question might be more appropriate on [Arquade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) as it's neiter about any computer nor game system (non mentioned so far), but pure game play. Don't you think?

Comment: its purely about the effects of physically manipulating retro harware. I beg to disagree

Comment: You ain't show no proof of anything but a quite botchered video with some strange claims that aren't even qualified. This is not a question about retro computing, not even about gaming. If at all, it's repeating blown up statements from that video without anything else. **After  having seen the video, I see no relation whatsoever to RC.SE**. There is not even a verifiable claim that the item in question happens as well. Voting now for close now ... hard decision ahead, as it's as unrelated as unclear .

Comment: how are the claims not "qualified"? I'm asking why a machine's hardware acts the way it does. What's the problem?

Comment: The video does not show anything happen, but cuts together some footage and adds voice over. No qualification of anything. And similar is the question. It not even names the system or exact game to be used, nor the exact setup nor any other information related to the claimed happening.  In fact, it does as well use a rather made up style pompous wordings. The way it is may fit some gamer boards, but not RC.SE

Comment: I named goldeneye (multiple times) which is exclusive to the n64.

Comment: Making cryptic remarks for insiders may be fine if you ask in some related game board. RC.SE is for a general public, therefor it's always a good idea to concentrate on facts and word a question in a way everyone can understand it - after all, don't you want them to help you? So make RC.SE a place with good questions, not insider trash talk. On a side note, to my knowledge Golden Eye is as well available for WII and DS, isn't it?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Erm, you might want to check the edits - he did only include that it is about the N64 version **after** my remark. The point is that, no matter what his level of knowledge (or assumption) is, a question should always include sufficient information to identify what it is about. The system in question being one of the most basic to add. Relaying on external knowledge for such is not a good idea. This is infact a good example for this, as his assumption ended being plain wrong.

Comment: 'Strategy' appears to be a euphemism for 'cheating' ?

Comment: @another-dave Well, it's only cheating if the rules say you can't do it. Sounds like it was a allowed until the moderators made their decision. I assume Trent suffered no punishment apart from having these runs taken down. It would be *really obvious* if the game froze, so I have to assume he was doing this technique openly, not trying to hide it.

Comment: [It's just not cricket](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it%27s+not+cricket)  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Many devices that may receive inputs at arbitrary times are designed to interrupt the processor whenever input arrives.  When the interrupt is triggered, it will be disabled until code finishes processing it, but in many cases, the interrupt will be re-enabled as soon as processing on that particular input is complete.  If something causes the interrupts to arrive much faster than expected, this may result in the CPU spending almost all of its time servicing the interrupts, and having very little time left over to do anything else.

On my first Commodore 64, one of the CIA chips had a defect which would cause it to interrupt continuously and also reset the "real time clock" if certain combinations of keys were held down (a weird behavior that was probably a result of a poor power-supply connection somewhere internal to the chip).  On that machine, games could be "paused" by pressing down such a key combination, though they would resume if the keys were released; such behavior did not occur on other machines.  I think something similar may be happening in this game, though I don't know enough about the particulars of how the controllers work to know the precise mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my *theory*: the N64 controller uses [basically a UART protocol](http://www.qwertymodo.com/hardware-projects/n64/n64-controller). The console (as instructed by the game code) sends a command to the controller and then receives a response. Because this is an asynchronous protocol, there's no required timing (like there would be in a SNES controller, which is synchronous). So the console will wait until it receives the response.

If the console doesn't receive a response it might try sending the same command again. And again. And again. And again. And so on until it actually receives a response.

By <s>physically breaking your hardware</s> messing with the circuit board in a specific way, if you can stop the responses getting back, it may cause the controller input function in the game code to get stuck, sending retries over and over. N64 games can be multithreaded. If the controller reading happens in the main game loop, but the countdown timer is its own thread, it could cause the described symptoms.

However, this is just a theory based on the described symptoms and the technical documentation of the controller protocol. It seems very likely, which is why I've dared to write it as an answer. Someone would need to actually test this on real hardware to confirm it.